How to assign keyboard shortcut to the "Run Tests" item in Visual Studio 2022 editor context menu?
Which command name corresponds to the "Run Tests" item in Visual Studio editor context menu (see picture)? I tried to assign EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.RunTests or RunTestsInCurrentContext but it does not work (neither the test is executed nor the keyboard shortcut shows up in the context menu).
For the second context menu item "Debug Tests", I cannot guess any command name at all.
When choosing the context menu items by mouse, the desired unit test is executed (or executed in debugger) properly as well as executing the tests from the Text Explorer.
Environment:

Visual Studio 2022
.NET Framework 4.8
NUnit 4.1.0
NUnit3TestAdapter 4.5.3


Here's how you can assign these commands to keyboard shortcuts:

Go to Tools > Options.
Navigate to Environment > Keyboard.
In the Show commands containing box, type
TestExplorer.RunAllTestsInContext for running tests or
TestExplorer.DebugAllTestsInContext for debugging tests. In the Press
shortcut keys box, press the key combination you want to assign.
Click Assign.


